# Visualforce Remoting and translations

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, translation, translation-workbench

Is it possible to `retreive` translated picklist values using VF Remote Objects?

For example, I have a Solution and I'm trying to get Solution.Status.

So I have the following:

```
  <apex:remoteObjects >
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Solution" fields="SolutionName,Id,Status" jsShorthand="Service"/>
  </apex:remoteObjects>
```

And then in JS, I do something like this:

```
new SObjectModel.Service().retrieve(
    {
      where: { .... criteria... },
      orderby: [{ CreatedDate: 'ASC' }],
      limit: 20
    },
    function (err, results, evt) {
      if (err) {
        onError(err);
      } else {
        results.forEach(function (sol) {
          console.log(sol.SolutionName, sol.Status);
        });
      }
    }
);
```

Right now, my console shows only untranslated values, and TOLABEL(Status) does not compile.  How can I get the translated versions?

Comment: Submitted Idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Di3TAAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this solution, but this is what I've done.  I haven't tested this for Mutliselect Picklists.

**JS Translator function:**

```
var getTranslator = function (translations) {
  return {
    _translationMap: translations,
    translate: function (objName, fieldName, picklistValue) {
      if (typeof picklistValue == 'string' || picklistValue instanceof String) {
        return (this._translationMap &&
            this._translationMap[objName] &&
            this._translationMap[objName][fieldName] &&
            this._translationMap[objName][fieldName][picklistValue]) ?
              this._translationMap[objName][fieldName][picklistValue] : picklistValue;
      } else { // array
        return picklistValue.map(function (val) {
          return this.translate(objName, fieldName, val);
        }, this);
      }
    }
  };
};
```

So to use it, I add in the following controller code:

**Controller Logic:**

```
public static List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult> getPicklistsFor(Schema.DescribeSObjectResult type) {
    List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult> rs = new List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult>();
    List<Schema.SObjectField> results = type.fields.getMap().values();
    for (Schema.SObjectField fld : results) {
        if(fld.getDescribe().isAccessible() &&
           (fld.getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Picklist ||
            fld.getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.MultiPicklist)) {
            rs.add(fld.getDescribe());
        }
    }
    return rs;

}

public static List<Schema.DescribeFieldResult> getSolutionPicklists() {
    return getPicklistsFor(Schema.SObjectType.Solution);
}
```

and then in JS, I do something a little more elegant than this (in reality I use a some [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)s):

```
  var translator = getTranslator(
      {
        'Account': {<apex:repeat value="{!accountPicklists}" var="fld">
          '{!fld.name}': {<apex:repeat value="{!fld.picklistValues}" var="pv">
            '{!JSENCODE(pv.value)}': '{!JSENCODE(pv.label)}',
          </apex:repeat>},
        </apex:repeat>},
        'Solution': {<apex:repeat value="{!solutionPicklists}" var="fld">
          '{!fld.name}': {<apex:repeat value="{!fld.picklistValues}" var="pv">
            '{!JSENCODE(pv.value)}': '{!JSENCODE(pv.label)}',
          </apex:repeat>},
        </apex:repeat>}
      }
    )
  });

 //  and when I want to use it, I do something like:
 translator.translate('Solution', 'Status', sol.get('Status'));
```

If there's a more natural way to do this (or a better way to write this bit up), I'd be very happy to hear it.